# Change text of custom dropdown on selecting an option

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, dropdown

I was working on a custom `dropdown` using **CSS and Vanilla JavaScript (Plain JS)**. I have tried the following code to select and set the `text` of dropdown on clicking an option:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let [...options] = document.querySelectorAll('#select .opt');
  let select = document.getElementById('select');
  
  select.addEventListener('click', () => {
    options.forEach(opt => {
      opt.classList.toggle('showOpt');
    });
  });
  options.forEach(opt => {
    opt.addEventListener('click', event => {
      let optArr = select.innerText.split('\n');
      optArr[0] = opt.innerText;
      select.innerText = optArr.join('\n');
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#select {
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.fas {
  float: right;
}
.opt {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.opt:hover {
  background: white;
}
.showOpt {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button id='select'>
  Level 1<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i><br/>
  <li class='opt' value='1'>Level 1</li>
  <li class='opt' value='2'>Level 2</li>
  <li class='opt' value='3'>Level 3</li>
  <li class='opt' value='4'>Level 4</li>
</button>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/Rahul_V7/pen/jKbYYg?editors=0010) is a pen of the above code.

> Now, let the user selected **Level 3** option.
> So, my question is, how can I **update the
>   dropdown text** (which is by default, Level 1) using `JavaScript / ES6`?

I have tried it using `element.innerText` function of JavaScript but it isn't working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap the header text of the `select` with a span so that you can target it later and change its `textContent` based on the `textContent` of the clicked item.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let [...options] = document.querySelectorAll('#select .opt');
  let select = document.getElementById('select');
  const selectHead = document.querySelector("#selectHeader");

  select.addEventListener('click', () => {
    options.forEach(opt => {
      opt.classList.toggle('showOpt');
    });
  });

  options.forEach(opt => {
    opt.addEventListener('click', event => {
      selectHead.textContent = event.target.textContent;
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#select {
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.fas {
  float: right;
}
.opt {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.opt:hover {
  background: white;
}
.showOpt {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button id='select'>
  <span id='selectHeader'>Level 1</span><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i><br/>
  <li class='opt' value='1'>Level 1</li>
  <li class='opt' value='2'>Level 2</li>
  <li class='opt' value='3'>Level 3</li>
  <li class='opt' value='4'>Level 4</li>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a style to the selected option and when clicked on an option, replace the `innerText` of the selected class by the inner text of the clicked option.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let [...options] = document.querySelectorAll('#select .opt');
  let select = document.getElementById('select');
  let selectedOption = document.querySelector('.visible');
  
  select.addEventListener('click', () => {
    options.forEach(opt => {
      opt.classList.toggle('showOpt');
    });
  });
  options.forEach(opt => {
    opt.addEventListener('click', event => {
      selectedOption.innerText = opt.innerText;
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#select {
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.fas {
  float: right;
}
.opt {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.opt:hover {
  background: white;
}
.showOpt {
  display: block !important;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button id='select'>

    <li class="visible">Level 1<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
    <li class='opt' value='1'>Level 1</li>
    <li class='opt' value='2'>Level 2</li>
    <li class='opt' value='3'>Level 3</li>
    <li class='opt' value='4'>Level 4</li>

</button>
```